# Replacing multiple strings that contain the pattern "No"

Tags: r, stringr

Looking at (somewhat) hectic survey data, and I want to turn all variations of "No" into a single "no" using stringR and str_replace(). The challenge is that I have observations like "No, No, No" all the way up to 9x consecutive Nos.

Can str_replace() or another function scoop up all these variations at once? Or ought I be righting many str_replace commands?

Here's a reprex of the dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(reprex)

dfr <- dput(global_filtered_numeric$x48_enforcement_participation [157:169])

dfr

[1] "No, No, No, No"                                           
 [2] "No"                                                       
 [3] "yes"                                                      
 [4] "yes"                                                      
 [5] "No"                                                       
 [6] "No"                                                       
 [7] "No"                                                       
 [8] "yes"                                                      
 [9] "yes, Yes male, yes, yes, Yes male, Yes female, Yes female"
[10] "yes, yes"                                                 
[11] "yes, yes"                                                 
[12] "No"                                                       
[13] "No"
```

First post/Reprex - so I'll test out if the df actually shows up with dput!

Comment: You can try something like `stringr::str_replace("No, No, No, No", "(No(,\\s)*)+", "No")`.

Comment: BTW, the real use of `dput(.)` as a means to provide unambiguous data for questions is not the running of it but its output. Most non-trivial objects will print `structure(...)` on the console, and it is that expression that would be useful here. In this example, since you're just `dput`ing a single column, it'll likely return `c("No, No, No, No", "No", ...)`, which would have been great to have (I mimicked it in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to go outside of base R here:

```r
vec <- c("No, No, No, No", "No", "yes", "yes", "No", "No", "No", "yes", "yes, Yes male, yes, yes, Yes male, Yes female, Yes female", "yes, yes", "yes, yes", "No", "No")
ifelse(nchar(gsub("[no, ]", "", vec, ignore.case = TRUE)), vec, "no")
#  [1] "no"                                                        "no"                                                       
#  [3] "yes"                                                       "yes"                                                      
#  [5] "no"                                                        "no"                                                       
#  [7] "no"                                                        "yes"                                                      
#  [9] "yes, Yes male, yes, yes, Yes male, Yes female, Yes female" "yes, yes"                                                 
# [11] "yes, yes"                                                  "no"                                                       
# [13] "no"
```

Comment: This was really helpful! First for the use of `dput()` and then for how to use `gsub`  I learned `tidyverse` and `dplyr` before Base R, so the syntax is a bit new to me. That all said, I really appreciate the help from both of you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using `vec` from r2evans, you can also use `gsub` as in:

```
> gsub("N[Oo].+", "No", vec)
 [1] "No"                                                       
 [2] "No"                                                       
 [3] "yes"                                                      
 [4] "yes"                                                      
 [5] "No"                                                       
 [6] "No"                                                       
 [7] "No"                                                       
 [8] "yes"                                                      
 [9] "yes, Yes male, yes, yes, Yes male, Yes female, Yes female"
[10] "yes, yes"                                                 
[11] "yes, yes"                                                 
[12] "No"                                                       
[13] "No"
```

Comment: I don't get that ... my `vec1` has plenty of empty strings, and they are carried forward with this code. My return from this code is `c("", "", "yes", "yes", ...)`. Did you mean using `vec` from my answer?

Comment: FYI, I edited my answer to remove `vec1` (only used once, moved it inline).

Comment: The OP didn't mention he has empty string in his dataset. Your answer is for more general framework, but mine is also useful for the OP question, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not saying the OP has empty strings. I'm saying that if you look at my previous version of `vec1` (which, by intent, had empty strings in it), running your `gsub(..., vec1)` preserved the empty strings, which was not the intent. If you use your code on my `vec` (both original and current), it works.

Comment: Ahh, I already updated my answer using your new `vec`